# How capture derivated this in base class into lambda function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, lambda, pthreads

I want to code a program that implements a base class and a derivated one of it.
I have to execute a thread in the base class that call a pure virtual function implemented into the derivated class.

When I compile and execute the program, the `Base::func()` is called instead `Derivated::func()` and my program crash because it cannot execute a pure virtual function. What I have to do to execute the derivated function.

**Note :** Multiple derivated classes can exist so I can't explicitly use `Derivated::func()`.

```cpp
class Base {
private:
    std::thread *t = NULL;
    virtual void func() = 0;


public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Base::foo() executed" << std::endl;

        this->t = new std::thread([this]() {
            while (true) {
                func();
            }
        });
    }
};

class Derivated : public Base {
public:
    void func() {
        std::cout << "Derivated::func() executed" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derivated d;
    d.foo();
}
```

I expect this result :

```
Base::foo() executed
Derivated::func() executed
Derivated::func() executed
Derivated::func() executed
Derivated::func() executed
Derivated::func() executed
...
```

But this is appear :

```
Base::foo() executed
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

Comment: The problem, it seems, is that the object destruction that happens when you leave `main` leaves you with an invalid `this` pointer. You need to exit *and join* the thread before the objects are being destructed (i.e. before the `main` function ends)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a thread is started, no attempt to join it is made, so the process happily terminate after calling `d.foo();` in `main`.

If you give a getter to the thread, in class `Base`

```
std::thread * theThread() { return t; }
```

in your `main`:

```
int main() {
    Derivated d;
    d.foo();

    d.theThread()->join();
}
```

This way the main thread gets blocked and the other thread is free to go on (and on).

Comment: While true, the error that the OP is asking about is something different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep, I just couldn't replicate it. Could you?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude chapeau :)

Comment: The example I made was flawed, it joins the thread to late to matter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sure it didn't solve the issue, but clearly explained the `pure virtual method called` exception

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

class Base {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t;
    virtual void func() = 0;

public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Base::foo() executed" << std::endl;    
        t = std::make_unique<std::thread>([this]() {
            for (int i=1; i<= 5; i++) {
                this->func();
            }
        });
        t->join();
    }
};

class Derivated : public Base {
public:
    void func() {
        std::cout << "Derivated::func() executed" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derivated d;
    d.foo();

}
```

**Ouput**:

```
Base::foo() executed
Derivated::func() executed
Derivated::func() executed
Derivated::func() executed
Derivated::func() executed
Derivated::func() executed
```